# how to set default content setting by specific user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I was looking for default content setting in WordPress then I found this code and it worked properly, but I want to set the different default content for new posts in WordPress by different users how can I do this,
**Example**
**user1:** new post-default content will be "FB is a largest social network"
**user2:** new post-default content will be "YT is largest videos web"
**user3:** new post-default content will be "TW is being used by officials globally"

how can I do this with different users and different default content set for the different author, contributor, editor, etc

**This code is working same on all users Admin, Editor, Author, Contributor**

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'add_default_content_to_wp_editor' );
function add_default_content_to_wp_editor($content) {

  $content = "<h2>You are not allowed to</h2><br>
  <p>
  <h3>comment unless you are logged in.</h3><br>
  <p>
  <b>No spammers! The Big Kahuna is watching</b><br>
  <p>";

  return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('default_content', 'my_editor_content', 10, 2);

function my_editor_content($content, $post)
{
   global $current_user;
   $user_roles = isset($current_user->roles[0]) ? $current_user->roles[0] : '';

   switch ($user_roles) {
       case 'administrator':
           $content = 'FB is a largest social network';
           break;
       case 'author':
           $content = 'YT is largest videos web';
           break;
       case 'editor':
           $content = 'TW is being used by officials globally';
           break;
   }
   return $content;
}
```

This may help you to set default content based on user role...
If have anything else let me know.
Thank you

Comment: code is working fine now 1 want to do 1 more thing 
for example I have 3 editors in our website but I want to set default content setting on specific user like 
Editor Role 1
Editor Role 2
Editor Role 3  


total 3 Editor Roles in our website we want to add default setting in just Editor Role 2 how can we do this please tell

Comment: In mine example it will only show for 3 user role administrator, editor, author